# Azure Load Balancer Remove front-end IP configuration Azure CLI not working

Tags: azure, azure-cli

Azure Load Balancer Remove front-end IP configuration Azure CLI not working.
In Microsoft documentation I found this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/remove-azloadbalancerfrontendipconfig?view=azps-8.3.0&tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-1

But when I tried it on my Azure it does not remove anything or write any errors.
Only it returns the load balancer json.

This is the code

```
$akslb = Get-AzLoadBalancer -Name $aksLoadBalancerName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
$configs = Get-AzLoadBalancerFrontendIpConfig -LoadBalancer $akslb
    
Remove-AzLoadBalancerFrontendIpConfig -Name "4df3610e6de64180bbb88a951d83a5ad" -LoadBalancer $akslb
```

Can someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I have Created two front-end IPs in the Load Balancer:

[image]

I observed that you cannot create the Azure Load Balancer without at least one front end IP.

[image]

It means either through portal or PowerShell Cmdlet, you cannot delete the frontend IP configuration from the Load balancer if it exists only one.

If a Load balancer contains single front end IP, then you can delete the load balancer itself using the below cmdlet:

```
Remove-AzLoadBalancer -Name "testwinvmlb" -ResourceGroupName "HariTestRG"
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the information, but I am not trying to remove the recourse itself. As you mentioned you must have at least one front end config and yes you do. But I have multiple configs and I'm trying remove the others.